# Change Keys of an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, key

I want to change such an object:

```
inputObj = {
    "1": 10,
    "2": 20,
    "3": 30,
    "4": 40,
    "5": 50,
    "6": 60
}`
```

to this:

```
outputObj = {
    "one": 10,
    "two": 20,
    "three": 30,
    "four": 40,
    "five": 50,
    "six": 60
}
```

can anybody help?
The keys are taken from the database as numbers. but I need to change them to descriptions

Comment: Looks like you've done it pretty well yourself. What more do you need?

Comment: Looks like you need to _map_ the keys.

Comment: somewhere you need to have the config for the keys like shown in the answer. Please check and let me know

Comment: Object.entries + array map + Object.fromEntries would seem to be the obvious way to do it

Comment: perhaps like `let outputObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(inputObj).map(([k,v])=>[{"1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four","5":"five","6":"six"}[k],v]));`

Answer (score 0):

i think the below snippet will solve the issue.

you need to take the key of input and map over it and change with replacementConfig and update it. See the below snippet

```js
const replacementsConfig = {"1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three"};
const data = {'1': 10, '2': 30 , "3": 69 };

let replacedItems = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  const newKey = replacementsConfig[key] || key;
  return { [newKey] : data[key] };
});

let output = Object.assign(...replacedItems)

console.log(output)
```